# WhatsApp didn't restore local backup, where can I find them?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, android-12

I wanted to clear & restore WhatsApp to make sure it deploys encrypted Google Drive backups. I've never done a Drive backup, only local. I made a local backup on the fly, then wiped WhatsApp data using app settings.

I re-registered to WA, but my chat history was totally blank! I found that the local directory `/sdcard/WhatsApp` was missing in Google Files app.

Panic again. I am now restoring a NAS backup of my WA directory, but I am surprised to see that, while the last synchronization occurred one week ago, all backup files are dated April 25th, 2021.

Does WhatsApp still store data in `/sdcard/WhatsApp`? Does it get deleted automagically when you clear WA data from settings? If I have to format my device and don't have Google Drive backups, what directories should I back up? Have I lost months of chat history?

If it matters, the device is Google Pixel 5, Android 12.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, it was because the Android file system policy has changed. I'll share it for reference.

Before Android 11, WhatsApp saved files under `/sdcard/WhatsApp`.

Starting from Android 11, and anyways since someday around April 25th, 2021, WhatsApp now stores data under `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp` to comply with A11 storage APIs.

I had FolderSync to sync all my `/sdcard` directory. In my own case, **except** for `/sdcard/Android` because of file permissions issues. So while the `/sdcard/WhatsApp` folder was already gone on my device, the last sync was made on April 25th (WA backups chats every day).

In the end, I lost 6 months of chat, not 10 years.

More, there's a **pitfall**. Deleting app from settings wipes `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp`, wiping backups and media. Uninstalling WA prompts for keeping or deleting data, but when you uninstall/reinstall WA, you have to register again.

In the end, I'll have to open another question why WA didn't deploy e2e encrypted backups.

Comment: "*Deleting app from settings wipes.. *"... How do you **delete** an app from settings? Guess you meant Uninstall). This and the next sentence need clarity (when you say uninstall which prompts you to keep data, are you uninstalling from Play store?)