# /sdcard/WhatsApp vs /sdcard/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Every time I have to backup my phone I end up with the same question, which one should I keep?
Is it a symlink? Can I delete one? Do I have duplicate files on my phone?

Comment: New WhatsApp versions no more use `/sdcard/WhatsApp` directory. They are 2 different directories, neither symlink, nor duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `/sdcard/Whatsapp` is the old, pre-Android 11 location where WhatsApp stored its data in the past. It's not used anymore.
- `/sdcard/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/` is the new, post-Android 11 location where WhatsApp stores its data.

They are not symlinked, nor duplicates.

The location was changed because [Android 11 enforces scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage). This means that apps cannot access arbitrary files on internal storage anymore, but only on their app-specific directory (`/sdcard/Android/.../[package.name]`) or public shared directory (`/sdcard/Pictures`, `/sdcard/Download`, etc.)

---

Related Q&A:

- [WhatsApp didn't restore local backup, where can I find them?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242742/44325)
- [WhatsApp doesn't prompt to restore from local storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203523/44325)