# Restore Whatsapp messages with local backup only (no google drive)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, google-drive, android-12

I won't bother you with the tedious details. I need to restore whatsapp messages from and old local backup and WA, not even searches for local backups.

A little more tunning: I've not used for some reasons (that are pointless to mention) for about a year. Last time, I created a backup (both local and GD) and uninstalled WA (I now assume this deletes the GD backup)

Nowadays I have to use it again.

The official guide claims (it's ridiculous) that you can ONLY restore from local backup on Android 9 or below

https://faq.whatsapp.com/6181521285295518/?helpref=hc_fnav&cms_platform=android

I thought that I could install WA on an old A9 phone, backup to GD and then install on my new phone. The information on the page is completely inaccurate. WA latest version does not even try to find a local backup on A9 or any other.

I used WA almost from it's launching and it's most vulnerable, annoying weakness is to restore messages from a backup. As long as I recall, every time it was a complete headache to restore the messages. My backup contains nearly fifteen years of messages, or in other words, about a million. Also, the stubbornness of WA of use primary storage, despite the Android (useless) adopted memory schema, resulted in memory filling up very fast (one of the reasons I dropped using it)

I also tried
[Whatsapp not doing local backup restore! (not Google Drive)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/237475/whatsapp-not-doing-local-backup-restore-not-google-drive)

but there is no solution there.

My conclusion at the time is that, if you DO NOT have a GD backup you're lost. A very nonsense restriction, and since you can not upload a backup to GD, again, you're lost.

How can I restore a local backup on A12 if I don´t have a GD backup?

Please no "why you didn't just kept WA running?","why you did that?" or "If you have not used over a year, why do you need to restore your messages?" comments or solutions

Comment: I honestly don't know when/if WhatsApp updated their FAQ mentioning Android 9, because our [canonical Q&A about restoring local backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203523/44325) has been working on Android 11 and later. What I noticed in WhatsApp's FAQ is that the location is outdated. [WhatsApp no longer uses `/sdcard/WhatsApp` folder anymore](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/256329/44325).